# Error with DVC on Google Colab - dvc.scm.CloneError: Failed to clone repo

Tags: git, dataset, google-colaboratory, dvc

I'm having a problem trying to run "dvc pull" on Google Colab. I have two repositories (let's call them A and B) where repository A is for my machine learning codes and repository B is for my dataset.

I've successfully pushed my dataset to repository B with DVC (using gdrive as my remote storage) and I also managed to successfully run "dvc import" (as well as "dvc pull/update") on my local project of repository A.

The problem comes when I use colab to run my project. So what I did was the following:

1. Created a new notebook on colab
2. Successfully git-cloned my machine learning project (repository A)
3. Ran "!pip install dvc"
4. Ran "!dvc pull -v" (This is what causes the error)

On step 4, I got the error (this is the full stack trace. Note that I changed the repo URL in the stack trace for confidentiality reasons)

```
2022-03-08 08:53:31,863 DEBUG: Adding '/content/<my_project_A>/.dvc/config.local' to gitignore file.
2022-03-08 08:53:31,866 DEBUG: Adding '/content/<my_project_A>/.dvc/tmp' to gitignore file.
2022-03-08 08:53:31,866 DEBUG: Adding '/content/<my_project_A>/.dvc/cache' to gitignore file.
2022-03-08 08:53:31,916 DEBUG: Creating external repo https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git@3a3f2019efabff8ec71429da39b86688d1c98e75
2022-03-08 08:53:31,916 DEBUG: erepo: git clone 'https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git' to a temporary dir
Everything is up to date.
2022-03-08 08:53:32,154 ERROR: failed to pull data from the cloud - Failed to clone repo 'https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git' to '/tmp/tmp2x6y9z0edvc-clone'
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scmrepo/git/backend/gitpython.py", line 185, in clone
    tmp_repo = clone_from()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 1148, in clone_from
    return cls._clone(git, url, to_path, GitCmdObjectDB, progress, multi_options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 1079, in _clone
    finalize_process, decode_streams=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 176, in handle_process_output
    return finalizer(process)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/git/util.py", line 386, in finalize_process
    proc.wait(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 502, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(remove_password_if_present(self.args), status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git clone -v --no-single-branch --progress https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git /tmp/tmp2x6y9z0edvc-clone

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/scm.py", line 104, in clone
    return Git.clone(url, to_path, progress=pbar.update_git, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scmrepo/git/__init__.py", line 121, in clone
    backend.clone(url, to_path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scmrepo/git/backend/gitpython.py", line 190, in clone
    raise CloneError(url, to_path) from exc
scmrepo.exceptions.CloneError: Failed to clone repo 'https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git' to '/tmp/tmp2x6y9z0edvc-clone'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/command/data_sync.py", line 41, in run
    glob=self.args.glob,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/pull.py", line 38, in pull
    run_cache=run_cache,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/fetch.py", line 50, in fetch
    revs=revs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 437, in used_objs
    with_deps=with_deps,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/repo/index.py", line 190, in used_objs
    filter_info=filter_info,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/stage/__init__.py", line 660, in get_used_objs
    for odb, objs in out.get_used_objs(*args, **kwargs).items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/output.py", line 918, in get_used_objs
    return self.get_used_external(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/output.py", line 973, in get_used_external
    return dep.get_used_objs(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/dependency/repo.py", line 94, in get_used_objs
    used, _ = self._get_used_and_obj(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/dependency/repo.py", line 108, in _get_used_and_obj
    locked=locked, cache_dir=local_odb.cache_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/external_repo.py", line 35, in external_repo
    path = _cached_clone(url, rev, for_write=for_write)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/external_repo.py", line 155, in _cached_clone
    clone_path, shallow = _clone_default_branch(url, rev, for_write=for_write)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return deco(call, *dargs, **dkwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/funcy/flow.py", line 274, in wrap_with
    return call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/external_repo.py", line 220, in _clone_default_branch
    git = clone(url, clone_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dvc/scm.py", line 106, in clone
    raise CloneError(str(exc))
dvc.scm.CloneError: Failed to clone repo 'https://gitlab.com/<my-dataset-repo-B>.git' to '/tmp/tmp2x6y9z0edvc-clone'
------------------------------------------------------------
2022-03-08 08:53:32,161 DEBUG: Analytics is enabled.
2022-03-08 08:53:32,192 DEBUG: Trying to spawn '['daemon', '-q', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp4x5js0dk']'
2022-03-08 08:53:32,193 DEBUG: Spawned '['daemon', '-q', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp6x11s0dk']'
```

And btw this is how I cloned my git repository (repo A)

```
!git config - global user.name "Zharfan"
!git config - global user.email "zharfan@myemail.com"
!git clone https://<MyTokenName>:<MyToken>@link-to-my-repo-A.git
```

Does anyone know why? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of DVC are you using? What system do you use?

Comment: I use DVC 2.9.2 on my local PC and it runs on Windows. However, on Google Colab (the environment that I faced the error on), I use DVC 2.9.5 @don_pablito

Comment: can you try to run `!git clone https://link-to-my-repo.git` in colab? does it work?

Comment: Yes I've already run !git clone https://link-to-my-repo.git and it did work. I managed to clone my repository. Only DVC isn't working now. @Shcheklein

Comment: okay, to clarify  - https://link-to-my-repo.git in the ERROR message - is it repo A or repo B, could you share the full `dvc pull -v` stack trace please, is it just a generic CloneError?

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying it earlier. link-to-my-repo.git is repo B. Noted, I've edited and added the full stack trace though I'm not sure whether it is a generic CloneError or not. But one thing for sure is that this only happens on Google Colab (DVC works perfectly on my PC). Thank you in advance! @Shcheklein

Comment: @ZharfanZahisham thanks for sharing more details. On collab - how (and) did you setup Git credentials (username, token, password, etc?).

Comment: I've added the commands that I ran to clone the repository in the question. Not sure if this helps but I'm using Gitlab to host my repository and used the access token from Gitlab to clone my repo. @Shcheklein

Comment: Thanks! But then the question, do you provide this token to DVC in some way? Is it saved in one of the `.dvc` files (the one that is created with `dvc import` on your local machine)?

Comment: No I think no token is saved in any .dvc file. I never had to pass any token when running "dvc import" or "dvc pull". I just copied the link to authorize DVC to access my Google account  and pasted it in the browser and got the token then pasted it on the CMD (this is when I do it on my local PC) so I expected it to also work the same way on Colab. @Shcheklein

Comment: I think the problem here is that DVC doesn't have access to gitlab private repo. When you was doing `dvc import` what URL did you specify - https? git?

Comment: I see. Hmm that makes sense since I didn't store my Gitlab token anywhere (I only passed it along in the URL when cloning repo A) which means DVC wouldn't have the access to my token. My PC on the other hand does store my Gitlab access token. You've given me a very helpful clue. I might have an idea on how to solve it. Thanks! And btw I use https. The URL looks something like this: https://gitlab.com/u/my-repo-b.git @Shcheklein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments thread.

Most likely it's happening since DVC can't get access to a private repo on GitLab. (The error message is obscure and should be fixed.)

The same way you would not be able to run:

```
!git clone https://gitlab.com/org/<private-repo>
```

It also returns a pretty obscure error:

```
Cloning into '<private-repo>'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
```

(I think it's something related to how tty is setup in Colab?)

The best approach to solve this is to use SSH like described [here](https://medium.com/@sadiaafrinpurba/how-to-clone-private-github-repo-in-google-colab-using-ssh-77384cfef18f) for example.

Comment: Using SSH did solve the issue, though I had to re-run "dvc import" again since the original .dvc file would pull using the https URL. Anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Update: Just found out I could just change the URL in the .dvc file so I wouldn't actually have to re-import the dataset repo haha I can't believe I missed out on that